# Remove all dots from directory name (shell)

Tags: bash

I've found several answers that look like they should work, but when I run a script to try and remove dots from directory names, the dots seem to confuse the script regardless of quoting. For instance, I have tried this on a directory named `s. om. e dir (25)`:

```
for dir in $(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name *.*); do
    mv "$dir" `echo "$dir" | tr '.' '_'`
done
```

and get this output in the terminal:

```
mv: rename ./s. to _/s_: No such file or directory
mv: rename om. to om_: No such file or directory
mv: rename e to e: No such file or directory
mv: rename dir to dir: No such file or directory
mv: rename (25) to (25): No such file or directory
```

How can I rename the directory from `s. om. e dir (25)` to `s_ om_ e dir (25)` without the code breaking at each instance of a dot?

Comment: Try `rename . _ */`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is using `for`/`in` on the output of `find`.

If you have the Perl version of `rename`, you can simply do

```
rename 'tr/./_/' *.*/
```

Otherwise,

```
for i in *.*; do
    [ -d "$i" ] || continue
    mv -- "$i" "${i//./_}"
done
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I don't have perl on the box I've got access to, and I didn't feel like waiting forever for the admins to install it, so thanks for the bash `for` loop! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `echo | tr`, you can simply use parameter substitution:

```
mv -- "$dir" "${dir//./_}"
```

You should use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop in a process substitution:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' dir; do
    mv -- "$dir" "${dir//./_}"
done < <(find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -name '*.*' -print0)
```

You should also quote your file pattern in `find`.

Moreover, since you're only iterating directories in the current directory, you can use this `glob`:

```
for dir in *.*/; do
    mv -- "$dir" "${dir//./_}"
done
```